# Introduction to mathematical logic from a finitist (and preferably also formalist) perspective

Tags: logic, reference-request, finitism

I'm soon going to be a 3rd year undergrad in pure math, and next semester i will have a class about logic. I already had a logic class before so have some familiarity with first order logic. I've always thought of math as being equivalent to manipulations of finite strings, so it bothers me that most books accept infinite objects in the metatheory. For example [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/155686) is written from a formalist point of view, but is not finitist.

I'm looking for a book that like the mentioned one, that serves as an introduction to logic and that accepts only finite objects in the metatheory, as i don't believe in the existence of infinite objects.

Comment: Can you give an example for infinite object from the book in the link for those who don't have the book?

Comment: @ℋolo they consider for example sets of all formulas, "rules" which are defined as possibly infinite relations, the closure of a set of formulas w.r.t. a rule. All of those will be infinite (usually).

Comment: You described those stuff perfectly fine using finite string of length 194. Even in formalism you can talk about infinite stuff: "∀n∈ℕ∃X⊆A s.t. |X|>n" is a finite string, for intuition (and for platonists), this "A" is an actual infinite object, but for pure formalists, "A" is just a symbol, and "∀n∈ℕ∃X⊆A s.t. |X|>n" is also just a string, and you can manipulate this string using some laws (deduction laws of First order logic in this example) to reach to a new string: "¬|A|<ω". the last statement is still a string, but intuitively it is an infinite object

Comment: If you don't want  to even talk about infinite objects, it is not formalism, it is finitism, and the 2 views (e.g. formalism, platonism,etc VS finitism, ultrafinitism,etc)  are independent, if you are tending towards finitism, you can still e platonist, and if you are formalist, you don't need to be finitist (although it is more common for finitism to go with formalism as a philosophical justification)

Comment: Sure, a formalist can talk about infinite objects. I'm a finitist too then, so i'd like the metatheory to be finitist.

Comment: A quick search for "Finitism as a Foundation for Mathematics" in google results with [this book](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2660192) and [this thesis](http://theses.gla.ac.uk/1344/).  I read neither of those 2, nor did I ever studied maths in a finitist context, so I can't really comment on their quality

Comment: Here is my standard challenge to a finitist: what is a string?

Comment: @RobArthan i don't know. I don't think there's such a thing as a string, when we talk about strings seems more like some intuitive high level thing that our brain seems to be able to reliably do somehow.